# How to run ajax in Wordpress Post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use ajax in wordpress
I have two comboboxes in single-meetings.php
the second combobox values are based on selection from the first one

here is my `single-meetings.php`

```
<form action="#" name="form" id="form" method="post">
<div id="check-in-date-wrap">
<select name="search_category"  id="check-in-date">
    <option value="03/10/2015">"03/10/2015"</option>
    <option value="03/11/2015">"03/11/2015"</option>
    <option value="03/12/2015">"03/12/2015"</option>
    <option value="03/13/2015">"03/13/2015"</option>
</select>   
<div id="check-out-date-wrap">
// a combobox should be created here
</div>
<img src="loader.gif" style="margin-top:8px; float:left" id="loader" alt="" />
<input type="submit" name="" value="GO" />
</form>
```

I have two another files, php and js

this is my php code
 `combo_check-out.php`

```
  <?php
        function iRange($first, $last, $format = 'm/d/Y' ) { 
        $dates = array();
        $current = strtotime($first);
        $i=1;
        while( $i <= $last ) { 
            $dates[] = date($format, $current);
            $current = strtotime('+1 day', $current);
            $i++;
        }

        $time = date("m/d/Y",$current);
        return $time;
    }

    if($_REQUEST)
    {
        $id     = $_REQUEST['parent_id'];
        ?>


        <select name="check-out"  id="check-out-date">
            <option value="<?php echo iRange($id, 1, $format = 'm/d/Y' ) ?>">"1 Day (Same Day)"</option>
            <option value="<?php echo iRange($id, 2, $format = 'm/d/Y' ) ?>">"2 Days"</option>
            <option value="<?php echo iRange($id, 3, $format = 'm/d/Y' ) ?>">"3 Days"</option>
            <option value="<?php echo iRange($id, 4, $format = 'm/d/Y' ) ?>">"4 Days"</option>
        </select>   

    <?php}?>
```

and here it is my js code
`combo_checkout_iRange.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#check-in-date').change(function(){
        $('#check-out-date-wrap').fadeOut();
        $('#loader').show();
        $.post("combo_check-out.php", {
            parent_id: $('#check-in-date').val(),
        }, function(response){
            setTimeout("finishAjax('check-out-date-wrap', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
        });
        return false;
    });
});

//JQuery to hide Loader and return restults
function finishAjax(id, response){
  $('#loader').hide();
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
} 

function alert_id()
{
    if($('#check-out-date').val() == '')
    alert('Please select a sub category.');
    else
    alert($("#check-out-date").val());
    return false;
}
```

they work fine outside wordpress

how to integrate them in wordpress theme

**Note:** this should work in post type called "meetings"
so this is what i wrote on `function.php`

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function() {

     if (is_single()) {
        if (get_post_type() == 'meetings')
        {
            wp_enqueue_script('combo_checkout_iRange', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/combo_checkout_iRange.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' ,true);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery in WordPress runs in no-conflict mode; that could be your problem. Change $(document).ready() to jQuery(document).ready(), etc. if your script isn't written in no-conflict mode. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Have you read [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) from the Codex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe one of the comments should fix your issue given how you mentioned that the code works outside of WordPress, which does in fact appear to be a problem with your references to $ instead of jQuery.

Also, i have written a post on this exact topic with step by step instruction, you can see it here:
[Ajax Calls in WordPress](http://primezerocafe.com/wordpress/ajax-calls-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Everything relevant should be in the answer, not at external link unless they are to some sort of official or semi official documentation.

Comment: Noted, i was going to put this as a comment but I can't post those yet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when I want to make a AJAX code I start the ajax registering by adding a ajax url accessible from the js.

```
wp_localize_script( "combo_checkout_iRange", "server_obj", array(
    "ajax_url"=>admin_url("admin-ajax.php")
) );
```

Than from the javascript file I could call the ajax server like that:

```
jQuery.post(server_obj.ajax_url, {'action':'The_ajax_action_name'},function(return) {})
```

And to make a function in PHP to handle the request and return the data to the client
add the following lines to your functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_The_ajax_action_name', 'The_ajax_action_name_ajax');           // for logged in user
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_The_ajax_action_name', 'The_ajax_action_name_ajax');    // if user not logged in

function The_ajax_action_name_ajax() {}
```

So "The_ajax_action_name" is the AJAX action parameter name and the postfix of the wp action hook called *wp_ajax_{name_goes_here}*